# How to test a instance of component use `ref` from native module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native

I have a problem with `mock` function

```
class MyScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.video = React.createRef();
  }
render() {
return (
  <VideoPlayer
    ref={this.video}
    onVideoSuccess={() => {
      this.video.current.startVideo();
    }}
  />);
 }
}
```

how can I test pass with `this.video.current.startVideo()`, i don't know how to mock this function `startVideo()`of component `VideoPlayer`

```
export default class VideoPlayer extends Component {
  startVideo() { ... }
  play() {...}
  pause() {...}
  stop() {...}
  render() {
    return <VideoPlayerView {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: This issue occur when I use this component on Modal. You can set timeout (300 millisecond for default display of Modal), it will work